# JMeter - CSV Config with same variables

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have 8 transaction (crud1, crud2) using 8 Transaction Controllers. I want each Thread (user) to perform all the 8 txns.  Txn 1-4 are different from txn 5-8.  The data for txn 1-4 are also different from txn 5-8.  However, they have similar fields like name, address, etc.

All txns will run within a Thread Group.

```
Thread Gp
|- txn1
   |- http req1
   |- http req2
   |- http req....
|- txn2
   |- http req1
   |- http req2
   |- http req....
|  .....
|- txn8
   |- http req1
   |- http req2
   |- http req....
```

I read from https://www.perfmatrix.com/jmeter-config-element/ and it seems like I can only have CSV config in Test Plan and Thread Group.  I've wanted to test duplicate names for different Transaction Controller and Samplers, however, I got inconsistent results.

1. Are CSV Config supported at the Controller and Sampler level ?
2. How do I handle the duplicate field names ?  I use unique field names for the different txns in the same CSV row for each Thread loop ?  Any other way ?
3. In terms of CSV Config scoping, how does JMeter handle duplicate field names at Test Plan, Thread Group, Controller, Sampler ?

Thanks

Edit:

"duplicate field names":  As I have 8 Transaction in each thread looping, there are some transaction using the same field name, eg Txn 1 has an "Address" field and Txn 2 also has an "Address" field but they have different values.  Since the CSV file is read per looping, I can only have 1 field called "Address".  Does it mean that I have to called it Address1 and Address2 ?  Is there feature in JMeter to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have CSV Data Set Config wherever you want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6tsk.jpg, CSV Data Set Config obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

I don't know what do you mean by "duplicate field names", by default JMeter reads next line from the CSV file on each iteration. If this is not something you're looking for - take a look at [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) setting.

Comment: "duplicate field names":  As I have 8 Transaction in each thread looping, there are some transaction using the same field name, eg Txn 1 has an "Address" field and Txn 2 also has an "Address" field but they have different values.  Since the CSV file is read per looping, I can only have 1 field called "Address".  Does it mean that I have to called it Address1 and Address2 ?  Is there feature in JMeter to handle this situation ?     I've taken a look at "Sharing Mode", I think it does not handle this situation.